# Event study: test for cumulative abnormal returns

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, finance

I am performing an event study, across different firms, using the market model theory.
$$\
{R_{it}=α_i+β_{i}R_{mt}+ε_{it}}$$

With Abnormal Returns (AR):`
$$AR_{it}=R_{it}−α_{i}−β_{i}R_{m
t}$$

How can I test the significance of CAR?
I.e.

$${H_0:CARR=0} $$ vs
$${H_a:CARR\neq0} $$
where $$CARR=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{T=-20}^{+20}\sum_{i=1}^{N}CAR_{ti}$$

Comment: Where did an identical question from yesterday go?

Comment: Could you kindly provide an answer, please

Comment: See Corrado "Event studies: A methodology review" (2011). MacKinlay "Event studies in economics and finance" (1997) is perhaps easier to read but I find it kind of sloppy.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate your help!